# Deploying a custom domain with Heroku and Domain.com

Tags: web, heroku, deployment, dns

I'm new to web dev and this would be my first proper deployment so apologies if this is a basic question. After following the steps on Heroku and Domain.com, my app is not showing at the desired url: [www.rocketcreative.agency](http://www.rocketcreative.agency)

**Heroku**
I've set up a basic web app (a draft version atm) on Heroku, and the code is working fine on https://hidden-sierra-22116.herokuapp.com . I've followed the Heroku instructions to generate a DNS target (cubic-orange-7jtaz36102kt9f8dir53koko.herokudns.com) for a domain I own ([www.rocketcreative.agency](http://www.rocketcreative.agency)) [Heroku Dashboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayYfx.png)

**Domain.com**
I added the DNS target to Domain.com as a CNAME (with 'www' as the host name). I've waited 24 hours for the changes to propagate, and DNS checking sites indicate that the DNS has propagated. I've spoken to Domain.com support and they said everything appears to be set up correctly. [Domain.com DNS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSnWj.png)

**Terminal:**
In the terminal, when I input `host www.rocketcreative.agency`, it returns `www.rocketcreative.agency is an alias for encircled-horseradish-4mpqnlzar9say364tz3hgy80.herokudns.com.`

**Browser Results for [www.rocketcreative.agency](http://www.rocketcreative.agency)**

Safari: 'Safari Can't Find The Server'

Chrome: 'www.rocketcreative.agency’s server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN'

I imagine this is a really basic question but if anybody could help that would be great. If there's any other info I need to provide please let me know. :)

Comment: Just realized the terminal response for the domain doesn't match the DNS target - the encircled-horseradish-4mpqnlzar9say364tz3hgy80.herokudns.com. was a CNAME I set up previously for rocketcreative.agency (without the www. prefix) and removed. 

Could that be the issue?

Comment: Hold the phone! I've solved this one, but I'll leave the question up incase anybody encounters the same. 

Ran the Heroku DNS Diagnostic tool and there were some issues with https:// - fixed by running:

`heroku domains -a hidden-sierra-22116`
`heroku ps:resize web=hobby`
`heroku certs:auto:enable`
`heroku certs:auto`

It said 'cert issued' and now the url works.

Comment: "Hold the phone! I've solved this one, but I'll leave the question up..."—[self-answers are encouraged here, but they should still be in the standard Q&A format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Please consider adding a proper answer below and, after the mandated waiting period, accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Hold the phone! I've solved this one, but I'll leave the question up incase anybody encounters the same. Ran the Heroku DNS Diagnostic tool and there were some issues with https:// - fixed by running:  heroku domains -a hidden-sierra-22116 heroku ps:resize web=hobby heroku certs:auto:enable heroku certs:auto It said 'cert issued' and now the url works